# Tezos LIGO send tezos from contract to an address using jsLigo

Tags: smartcontracts, tezos

I am going to send tezos from contract to an address using jsLigo

```
if (amount > (0 as tez)) {
      let receiver: contract<unit> =
        match ((Tezos.get_contract_opt(sender) as option<contract<unit>>), {
          Some: (contract) => contract,
          None: () => failwith("Contract not found.")
        });

       Tezos.transaction(unit, (amount as tez), receiver);
}
```

I am getting this error while building.

```
Invalid type(s)
Cannot unify operation with unit.
```

[image]

And I am not sure it is correct method to send tezos.